# Android SDK can't be found at location

Tags: android, sdk, flutter-dependencies

I have tried without any success to make Flutter find the Android SDK I installed at the root of my computer.

I am not using Android Studio, so I downloaded the Android SDK from the site and set the ANDROID_HOME PATH to point to the location where I installed the SDK. I wish to use VS Code for Android development.

This is the result of running `flutter doctor`.

```
C:\flutter>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 20e59316b8 (5 weeks ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
    • Engine revision fee001c93f
    • Dart version 2.4.0

[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X ANDROID_HOME = C:\tools
      but Android SDK not found at this location.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] VS Code (version 1.37.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Cliff\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.3.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

C:\flutter>
```

I expected Flutter to find the Android SDK where I installed it. Please help

Comment: I need help with this please. I have checked threads raised on this issue and non has helped me solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

@cliff , i think you are setting wrong sdk path to the ANDROID HOME PATH variable

Comment: I have tried virtually everything suggested, but still, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set exact path of Android SDK to environment variable.

For example, in windows, set environment variable like this:
Details: https://www.360logica.com/blog/how-to-set-path-environmental-variable-for-sdk-in-windows/

### Update:

Your android home is now `c:\tools`, and it seems that it is wrong path.

> ANDROID_HOME = C:\tools

Maybe "C:\tools\android-sdk"? Please check it is really android home path.

To verify android home environment variable, use cmd. Type your android home in your cmd screen.

```
>echo %ANDROID_HOME%
```

If you get the exact same path with your android home, your environment variable is correctly set.

Or, you can just use Android studio.

Comment: I followed the instructions on the link, but nothing changed.